# LINQ join statement to check if number exist in another join table

Tags: linq

I am having a bug in editing the following LINQ Query

```
var tNumber = 10001;


var data = from r in R_TABL
                               join pt in PT_TABL
                                   on r.R_id equals pt.id into trans
                               join tu in TU_TABL
                                   on tNumber equals tu.tUNUMBER
                               from tr in trans.DefaultIfEmpty()
                               where r.r_number == tNumber &&
                                     r.sequence == "101001"

                               select new MyDto
                               {

                                   IsExisting = tu.tUNUMBER != null ? true : false
                               };
```

I added the following line:

```
join tu in TU_TABL on tNumber equals tu.tUNUMBER
```

and

```
IsAppAssist = tu.tUNUMBER != null ? true : false
```

I need to join the TU_TABL to check if number exist in the table. In the c# method I pass in the parameter, tNumber and check on the 
"join tu in TU_TABL on tNumber equals tu.tUNUMBER" to see if there is a match. I create a new DTo and set the boolean IsExisting to if tu.tuNumber != null.

If the number exists, IsExisting is true, else false.

When I checked the result, all the records coming back are false. What is the correct way to correct the linq join to check if a number exist in the join table?

Answer (score 1):

The left side of your `equals` clause does not check against a column; you should be comparing it to `r`'s `t_number`:

```
join tu in TU_TABL
    on r.r_number equals tu.tUNUMBER
```